# Get number of products from each category in mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, e-commerce

I'm new to mongodb and to overall databases side of development.

I'm trying to make a product listing site where all the categories would be displayed with the number of products within that particular category and when clicked on a particular category, it would get me all the products in that category.

Some things to note are:

- every product will have only one category
- each category will have multiple products

I don't know how to go about this problem and tried searching it online but couldn't exactly find what I was looking for. I've also tried making the schema for this but I do not know if it's the right approach or not and this is how it looks:

```
const productsSchema = {
    category: String,
    name: String,
    price: String,
    description: String,
    thumbnail: String,
};
```

*Side note: I'm using MERN stack.(if its of any help)*

Answer (score 1):

If I've understand well your question, you can use something like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "category": "category1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$count": "total"
  }
])
```

With this query you will get the total `$count` for each category.
Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zyjYbE7FdiD)

In your `frontend` you will need a call for every `category`.

Maybe if your DB has a lot of different categories this is not a good approach, but if the number is not large enough you can call this query a couple times and you will get the result you want.

MongoDB Documentation reference [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should have a product schema and a product category schema, where the product category schema has an array of product ids that belong to that category.

In the product schema, you could also have a pointer to the category object that a product is linked to (as opposed to just the name of the category as a string).

Maybe take a look at mongoose populate https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html